# How to determine the value for n in the Gibbs free energy and redox potential equation?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, free-energy

I am having a problem with this equation for redox potentials

$$\Delta G = -nFE_\mathrm{cell}$$

In this equation I never am totally sure about what the value of $n$ should be, for example for the reaction shown below, would the $n$ be 2 electrons or 1 electron? Personally, I think it should be 2 electrons because that is the number of mol of electron under the simplest whole number ratio.

\begin{align}
\ce{cyt $c$(Fe^3+) + e- &-> cyt $c$(Fe^2+)}\\
\ce{NADH &-> NAD+ + H+ + 2e- }\\
\end{align}

I think this is a different matter than in the already answered question "[Does the relationship equation between standard cell potential and equilibrium constant violate potential's intensive properties?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/28954/4945)" Because in that Nernst equation the change in $n$ would be balanced by the change in the equilibrium constant. I assume that you are insinuating that there is one of the variables here which will correct for the increase in $n$. I don't see which would, as $E_\mathrm{cell}$ should be independent of quantity and $F$ is a constant.

Comment: Do you think your question is similar to [this one](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/29283/1499), Matthieu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Personally, I think it should be 2 electrons because that is the
>   number of mol of electron under the simplest whole number ratio.

Yes, it is $\ce{2e-}$.

Assuming that the two reactions provided above are half-reactions, the $n$ has to be $2$.

$E_\mathrm{cell}$ is independent of quantity because it is an *intensive property*. It does not depend on the amount of matter present. The $n$ accounts for the number of moles of $\ce{e-}$, this is used to calculate $\Delta G$, *which in turn depends on the amount of matter present*.

Overall, one must understand that $E_\mathrm{cell}$ is just the *difference in cell potentials of two half-reactions*. *Increasing* or *decreasing* the amount of both does not matter.

Comment: This statement that $n$ "has to be 2" is not correct. By no means does $n$ *have* to be 2, it can be anything OP so chooses.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is not correct, the number $n$ is not equal to 2 simply because 2 is the lowest common multiple of 2 and 1. Furthermore $n$ is not the "number of moles of electrons", which would have units of $\pu{mol}$; $n$ is in fact *dimensionless*.

---

In fact the number $n$ can be anything you like, and it depends on how you combine the two half-equations.

To use a different (not very realistic, but I don't care) example consider the half-reactions (data from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)))

$$\begin{align}
\ce{Na+(aq) + e- &-> Na(s)} & E_1 &= \pu{-2.71 V} \tag{1} \\
\ce{Br2 (l) + 2e- &-> 2Br-(aq)} & E_2 &= \pu{+1.07 V} \tag{2} \end{align}$$

We have $E_\mathrm{cell} = E_2 - E_1 = \pu{+3.78 V}$. To construct a full reaction for this cell the "usual" procedure taught is to take (1), multiply it by 2, and subtract it from (2).

$$\ce{Br2(l) + 2Na(s) -> 2Na+(aq) + 2Br-(aq)} \tag{3}$$

In this case, we have $n = 2$ as there are two electrons being transferred in this reaction, from bromine to sodium. Equivalently, you can think of (3) as being the sum of two half-reactions, each featuring the gain or loss of two electrons:

$$\begin{align}
\ce{2Na(s) &-> 2Na+(aq) + 2e-} \tag{4} \\
\ce{Br2(l) + 2e- &-> 2Br-(aq)} \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

Note that the stoichiometric coefficient of $\ce{e-}$ - the number in front of the electrons - is 2, for both half-equations.

---

However, you could easily construct a different full reaction, simply differing from (3) by a multiplicative factor. There's no reason why you cannot, for example, divide (2) by 2, then subtract (1) to get:

$$\ce{1/2 Br2(l) + Na(s) -> Na+(aq) + Br-(aq)} \tag{3*}$$

and here you should only have $n = 1$, because there is only one electron being transferred here, from bromine to sodium. Again you can decompose this into its half-reactions:

$$\begin{align}
\ce{Na(s) &-> Na+(aq) + e-} \tag{4*} \\
\ce{1/2Br2(l) + e- &-> Br-(aq)} \tag{5*}
\end{align}$$

and the stoichiometric coefficient of $\ce{e-}$ here is simply 1.

---

The bottom line is that

- $E_\mathrm{cell}$ doesn't change with the stoichiometric coefficients.
- $n$ does, and hence $\Delta G = -nFE_\mathrm{cell}$ does. *Your choice* of the full cell reaction determines the value of $n$ you work with.
- The best definition of $n$ is the **stoichiometric coefficient of the electrons in the half-reactions into which the cell reaction can be divided** (Atkins & de Paula, *Physical Chemistry*).